# Weird exception behavior with try-finally block

Tags: java, android, exception

I'm creating Android application and some weird behavior is happening related to handling exceptions when a try-finally bock is used.

Why the output of following code is `NullPointerException` instead of `SocketTimeoutException`?

```
consumeSomeService();
[...]
private void consumeSomeService() {
    try {
        getResponse();

    } catch (SocketTimeoutException ste) {
        Log.d("tag", "SocketTimeoutException");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("tag", e.getClass().getName());
    }
}

private static void getResponse() throws SocketTimeoutException {
    try {
        throw new SocketTimeoutException();

    } finally {
        Log.d("tag", "finally!"); // No matter what is here, always throw NullPointerException
    }
}
```

If remove the `finally` block, it works as expected.

This same code on PC/desktop result the `SocketTimeoutException` correctly.

EDIT: The stacktrace, where "MyActivity.java:38" is always the last line inside `finally` block.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at mycompany.exceptiontest.MyActivity.getResponse(MyActivity.java:38)
at mycompany.exceptiontest.MyActivity.consumeSomeService(MyActivity.java:21)
at mycompany.exceptiontest.MyActivity.onCreate(MyActivity.java:16)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: @RichardLeMesurier: I'm using Android Studio 0.8.9 and I've tried with 2 different GenyMotion emulators (API 16 and 17). There's no more code, just that at onCreate(). If throwing another exception from `finally` the correct `catch` is called.

Comment: Tested with real Samsung Galaxy Tab 4 (SM-T531) with Android 4.4.2 with same wrong behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Converting comments to answer to provide more space...

Below some basic ideas which test all our assumptions about what's going on.

I think GenyMotion runs a real copy of Android, so I'd expect it to run the same as the device.

Tested on real Nexus 7 running 4.4.4 it does as expected.

---

Test the `finally` by putting some code that can't possibly throw a null pointer exception.

```
private static void getResponse() throws SocketTimeoutException {
    try {
        throw new SocketTimeoutException();
    } finally {
        int i = 1;
        if (i==1) {i++;}
    }
}
```

It would be interesting to see which line gives a problem in this case.

---

Test problems with `SocketTimeoutException` by throwing something else.

```
private void consumeSomeService() {
    try {
        getResponse();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("tag", e.getClass().getName());
    }
}

private static void getResponse() throws Exception {
    try {
        throw new Exception();
    } finally {
        Log.d("tag", "finally!");
    }
}
```

---

For interest, test behaviour by inlining method `getResponse()`.

```
private void consumeSomeService() {
    try {
        throw new SocketTimeoutException();
    } catch (SocketTimeoutException ste) {
        Log.d("tag", "SocketTimeoutException");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("tag", e.getClass().getName());
    } finally {
        Log.d("tag", "finally!");
    }

}
```

Comment: "... putting some code that can't possibly throw a null pointer exception": The NPE continues to be thrown after last line of `finally`

Comment: "... throwing something else": No difference. Same NPE behavior.

Comment: "... test behaviour by inlining method": It works as expected BUT this approach can't be used because the real application involves auto-generated code.

Comment: @LuisRigoni I'm stumped, sounds very odd, especially your findings. I'll leave this post up as community wiki as "proof" of what's going on. Good luck